# What was the cost to produce one episode of Galaxy Rangers?

Tags: production, galaxy-rangers

I remember reading somewhere that the production was, at the time, USD $1,000,000 per episode. The only source I could find now is a comment on amazon, stating

> the entire production cost $65 million dollars or $1 million dollars per episode [ref](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adventures-Galaxy-Rangers-Collection-Region/dp/B00199PP6U) <sup>thanks @Valorum</sup>

Is there a reputable source for this figure?

Comment: @Valorum many thanks.

Comment: I'm still wondering what (if anything) you'd like to see before considering an acceptance.

Comment: A reminder? I mean, the me of six years ago was pretty dumb. Now I'm slightly less dumb and just a iota wiser.

Comment: And I now know the difference between comparable and comparative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Best guess, approx $300k+ per episode.

The show's creator, Robert Mandell indicated in an interview with Starlog that his show wasn't *dramatically* more expensive than comparable shows in its market space. Where it differed was that they were making enough shows (65 episodes) to go into *immediate* syndication and that the studio were planning to make their money back from *overseas* syndication rather than a tie-in to a major plastic toy brand.

> *"The syndication marketplace was just starting to explode in '84
> because of the sucess of "He-Man & The Masters of the Universe".
> He-Man really set the trend for producing animation with heavy toy company involvement. Toy companies have always been involved in
> Saturday morning animation, but never to the extent that they were
> producing 65 half hours of animation. It's an extremely expensive
> endeavor. **The average cost per strip has been somewhere near $15
> million,** which is a phenomenal amount of money  - it's like the budget
> for a major motion picture. Most companies that get involved are
> really looking for the big toy hit, because it's the only way a
> financier can expect a return."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Starlog #121 August 1987](http://home.mindspring.com/%7Eallronix/galaxy_rangers/grinfo/starlog.htm)</sup></sub>